# How does pyspark write overwrite mode work with s3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to save a dataframe in s3 using pyspark. There already exists a bunch of files from a previous run of pyspark. In my current run, I am trying to overwrite the existing files with data from my new dataframe (which already consists of the old data). I am using the 'overwrite' mode provided by pyspark to handle this. How exactly does this work? Does S3 delete all the files in the directory, before writing to new files with the new data, and if this is the case, is there a possibility that S3 delete might fail when there are lots of existing files in the directory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete action is async. You can read the aws doc on [DeleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html).